# SQL Delete row if no relationships present

Tags: sql, join, sql-delete

I have a Purchase Order table and an items table, a Purchase Order can have many Items but I want to remove all those purchase orders that have no items. Is that possible in SQL?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: This is an easily found duplicate. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts. When you do have a researched non-duplicate code question give a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.

```
delete from purchase_orders
    where not exists (select 1
                      from purchase_order_items poi
                      where poi.purchase_order_id = purcahse_orders.purchase_order_id
                     );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `not exists`.

Assuming that your table structures are like:

```
purchase_orders(id)
purchase_order_items(purchase_order_id)
```

Where `purchase_order_id` in table `purchase_order_items`is foreign key to `id` in table `purchase_orders`, that would look like:

```
delete from purchase_orders po
where not exists (
    select 1 from purchase_order_items poi where poi.purchase_order_id = po.id
)
```